# Symfony redirect to external URL

Tags: symfony, redirect, header, response

How can I redirect to an external URL within a symfony action?

I tried this options :

```
1- return $this->redirect("www.example.com");
```

Error : No route found for "GET /www.example.com"

```
2- $this->redirect("www.example.com");
```

Error : The controller must return a response (null given).

```
3- $response = new Response();
$response->headers->set("Location","www.example.com");
return $response
```

No Error but blank page !

Comment: First one should work also can you specify which version you are using

Comment: symfony/symfony                          v2.6.6

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Answer to your question is in official Symfony book.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->redirect('http://stackoverflow.com');
    // return $this->redirect('http://stackoverflow.com', 301); - for changing HTTP status code from 302 Found to 301 Moved Permanently
}
```

What is the `"URL"`? Do you have really defined route for this pattern? If not, then not found error is absolutelly correct. **If you want to redirect to external site, always use absolute URL format.**

Comment: What you've provided is redirect to existing URL in application. If you look closely at OP's title, you will notice that he is asking about *external* Url. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: You are right. I have badly copy an example from official doc.

Comment: This does NOT answer the question, which is to redirect to an EXTERNAL url

Comment: I'm sorry but I think `http://stackoverflow.com` is an EXTERNAL URL :). Can you explain more deeply why do you think it's bad answer?

Comment: This answer calls the Symfony2 `Controller::redirect` method, which is the equivalent of calling `new RedirectResponse` when navigating to a symfony route.  https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/2.8/Controller/Controller.php#L80 Both of which are the same as specifying `header('Location: http://www.example.com');` Effectively the issue was that `http://` was not included in the OP's question, as all `RedirectResponse` does is extend `Response` and calls `$this->headers->set('Location', $url)` and setting the content to include a `meta refresh` as the content body.

Answer (score 33):

You have to use **RedirectResponse** instead of **Response**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

And then:

```
return new RedirectResponse('http://your.location.com');
```

Comment: This was the only way I could get symfony to redirect in such a way that the browser url changed (for internal redirection).

Comment: @beterthanlife I'm glad it was helpful to you.

Comment: @Artamiel thanks man. This one worked for external links. Selected Answer did not work for me for some reason.